# How to clone project onto GCE using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, google-compute-engine

I have the below ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: agent
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Launch gcp instance
      gce:
        instance_names: test-gcp-instance
        zone: us-central1-a
        machine_type: n1-standard-1
        image: ubuntu-1604
        state: present
        service_account_email: "mydetails@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
        credentials_file: "Kcreds.json"
        project_id: "kubernetes-test-project-v1"


    - name: Clone project to be run
      git:
        repo: https://github.com/projects.git
        dest: ~/
      become: no
```

This creates an instance of google cloud.  However I want to be able to (as in the second task) clone the project directly on to the instance. I cannot figure out how to do this or find an example of how its been done.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a GCP project is not possible as of now. That’s being said, there is an existing feature request to implement this functionality. I would recommend you to visit [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/115444933) issue-tracker link and provide your valuable suggestions over there. A possible workaround will be

1. Create an image from the [persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#bundle_image) of the instance that you created;
2. Create your new project;
3. Recreate the instance using the [image from the first project](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects#accessing_images).

The links provided are for GCP, but you might be able to find the correspondent commands for Ansible.